# Error to cloning project with puppet on vagrant

Tags: django, git, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to install django and clone a github project with a puppet script. I am using modules as follows:

- files

  - (empty directory)
- manifests

  - nodes.pp
  - web.pp
- modules

  - django

    - manifests

      - init.pp
    - files

      - (empty directory)
  - git

    - manifests

      - init.pp
    - files

      - (empty directory)
  - postgres

Within the **web.pp** file I have:

```
import ' nodes.pp '
```

In **nodes.pp** file I have:

```
node default {
        include postgres
        include git
        include django
    }
```

In **init.pp** file within the Manifests folder that is inside the git folder I have the following code:

```
class git{
    include git::install
}

class git::install{
    package { 'git:':
        ensure => present
    }
}

define git::clone ( $path, $dir){
    exec { "clone-$name-$path":
        command => "/usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:$name $path/$dir",
        creates => "$path/$dir",
        require => [Class["git"], File[$path]],
    }
}
```

In **init.pp** file within the Manifests folder that is inside the django folder I have the following code:

```
class django{
    include django::install, django::clone, django::environment
}

class django::install {
    package { [ "python", "python-dev", "python-virtualenv", "python-pip",
                "python-psycopg2", "python-imaging"]:
        ensure => present,
    }
}

class django::clone {
    git::clone { 'My GitHub repository name':
        path => '/home/vagrant/',
        dir => 'django',
    }
}

 define django::virtualenv( $path ){
     exec { "create-ve-$path":
         command => "/usr/bin/virtualenv -q $name",
         cwd => $path,
         creates => "$path/$name",
         require => [Class["django::install"]],
     }
 }

class django::environment {
    django::virtualenv{ 've':
        path => '/usr/local/app',
    }
}
```

To run the scripts puppet I use the command:

```
sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/vagrant/modules /vagrant/manifests/web.pp
```

and run this command I get the following **error**:

```
Could not find dependency File[/home/vagrant/] for 
Exec[clone-My GitHub repository name-/home/vagrant/] at 
/vagrant/modules/git/manifests/init.pp:16
```

Note: where is the name 'My GitHub repository name', I put the name of my github repository correctly.

What is wrong and how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

in your define git::clone have you made sure to declare the file resource for $path?

you should have:

```
file { $path: ensure => directory }
```

you can't *require* a resource that you haven't specifically delcared